# X axis Line not displayed in Firefox if Brush functionality applied on X axis

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 to create two level grouped category bar chart with brush functionality on x axis.But X axis line not displayed in FireFox even though i didn't add any css  related to hide x axis.
X axis line appeared in Chrome and IE.
NOTE:here also if we click on Full Page x axis line display.else it doesn't display.

```js
// Code goes here



var barsData = [
   {
      "value":100,
      "key":"03-08-2016,0",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome49"
   },
   {
      "value":40,
      "key":"04-08-2016,1",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome49"
   },
   {
      "value":20,
      "key":"05-08-2016,2",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome49"
   },
   {
      "value":100,
      "key":"03-08-2016,3",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome50"
   },
   {
      "value":27,
      "key":"04-08-2016,4",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome50"
   },
   {
      "value":57,
      "key":"05-08-2016,5",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome50"
   },
   {
      "value":40,
      "key":"04-08-2016,6",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox44"
   },
   {
      "value":60,
      "key":"05-08-2016,7",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox44"
   },
   {
      "value":50,
      "key":"04-08-2016,8",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome47"
   },
   {
      "value":40,
      "key":"05-08-2016,9",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome47"
   },
   {
      "value":80,
      "key":"04-08-2016,10",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox45"
   },
   {
      "value":60,
      "key":"05-08-2016,11",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox45"
   },
   {
      "value":0,
      "key":"04-08-2016,12",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/IE10"
   },
   {
      "value":40,
      "key":"05-08-2016,13",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/IE10"
   },
   {
      "value":50,
      "key":"04-08-2016,14",
      "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox42"
   }
];
var osLevelData = [
   {
      "key":"Windows 7/Chrome49",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":100,
            "key":"03-08-2016,0",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome49"
         },
         {
            "value":40,
            "key":"04-08-2016,1",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome49"
         },
         {
            "value":20,
            "key":"05-08-2016,2",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome49"
         }
      ],
      "centerBarPosVal":"03-08-2016,0",
      "lastBarPosVal":"05-08-2016,2"
   },
   {
      "key":"Windows 7/Chrome50",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":100,
            "key":"03-08-2016,3",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome50"
         },
         {
            "value":27,
            "key":"04-08-2016,4",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome50"
         },
         {
            "value":57,
            "key":"05-08-2016,5",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome50"
         }
      ],
      "centerBarPosVal":"03-08-2016,3",
      "lastBarPosVal":"05-08-2016,5"
   },
   {
      "key":"Windows 7/Firefox44",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":40,
            "key":"04-08-2016,6",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox44"
         },
         {
            "value":60,
            "key":"05-08-2016,7",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox44"
         }
      ],
      "centerBarPosVal":"04-08-2016,6",
      "lastBarPosVal":"05-08-2016,7"
   },
   {
      "key":"Windows 7/Chrome47",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":50,
            "key":"04-08-2016,8",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome47"
         },
         {
            "value":40,
            "key":"05-08-2016,9",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Chrome47"
         }
      ],
      "centerBarPosVal":"04-08-2016,8",
      "lastBarPosVal":"05-08-2016,9"
   },
   {
      "key":"Windows 7/Firefox45",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":80,
            "key":"04-08-2016,10",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox45"
         },
         {
            "value":60,
            "key":"05-08-2016,11",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox45"
         }
      ],
      "centerBarPosVal":"04-08-2016,10",
      "lastBarPosVal":"05-08-2016,11"
   },
   {
      "key":"Windows 7/IE10",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":0,
            "key":"04-08-2016,12",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/IE10"
         },
         {
            "value":40,
            "key":"05-08-2016,13",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/IE10"
         }
      ],
      "centerBarPosVal":"04-08-2016,12",
      "lastBarPosVal":"05-08-2016,13"
   },
   {
      "key":"Windows 7/Firefox42",
      "values":[
         {
            "value":50,
            "key":"04-08-2016,14",
            "secondKey":"Windows 7/Firefox42"
         }
      ],
      "centerBarPosVal":"04-08-2016,14",
      "lastBarPosVal":"04-08-2016,14"
   }
];



var barColor = "#4A7B9D";

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 860 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var min_margin = {
    top: height,
    right: margin.right + 10,
    bottom: margin.bottom,
    left: margin.left + 10
  },
  min_height = 10,
  min_width = 860 - min_margin.left - min_margin.right;

//first scale
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

//second scale
var groupx = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

//scroll scale
var min_x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

//y scale
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

//Add domain for X scale  
x.domain(barsData.map(function(d) {
  
  return d.key;
}));

//Add domain for X scale  
groupx.domain(osLevelData.map(function(d) {
  return d.key;
}));

//scroll domain
min_x.domain(barsData.map(function(d) {
  return d.key;
}));
//domain Y
y.domain([0, d3.max(barsData, function(d) {
  return d.value;
})]);

//x axis 
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickFormat(function(d){
   return d.split(",")[0];
  })
  .orient("bottom");

//group axis
 var groupAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(groupx)
  .tickFormat(function(d){
   return d;
  })
  .orient("bottom");

//scroll axis
var min_xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(min_x)
  .tickFormat(function(d){
   return d;
  })
  .orient("bottom");


var main_xZoom = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0, width]);

// y axis 
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .tickFormat(function(d){
   return d;
  })
  .orient("left")

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", 800 + margin.top + margin.bottom);

//main g
var main = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

main.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height + min_height + margin.bottom);

// Add the x axis DOM elements
var xDOM = main.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + min_height) + ")")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .call(xAxis)
  //.selectAll(".tick text")
  //.call(wrap, x.rangeBand());
  xDOM.selectAll(".tick").append("line")
  .attr("class","groupline")
  .attr("y2",30)
  .attr("transform", function(d,index) {
     /*var  position;
      osLevelData.forEach(function(ddd){
        if(ddd.key === d){
          position = ddd.lastBarPosVal;
        }
      })*/
     return "translate(" + (x.rangeBand()/2) + ",0)";
     //console.log("d ..",d);
    });

  // Add the group axis DOM elements
  var groupDOM = main.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x1 axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + min_height + 30) + ")")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .call(groupAxis)
  .selectAll(".tick")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
     var  centerPos;
      osLevelData.forEach(function(ddd){
        if(ddd.key === d){
          centerPos = ddd.centerBarPosVal;
        }
      })
     return "translate(" + (x(centerPos)+(x.rangeBand()/2)) + ",0)";
    });
  //.selectAll(".tick text")
  //.call(wrap, groupx.rangeBand());
  groupDOM.append("line")
  .attr("class","groupline")
  .attr("y2",30)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
     var  lastPos;
     var  centerPos;
      osLevelData.forEach(function(ddd){
        if(ddd.key === d){
          lastPos = ddd.lastBarPosVal;
          centerPos = ddd.centerBarPosVal;
        }
      })
     return "translate(" + ((x(lastPos)+x.rangeBand()) - (x(centerPos)+(x.rangeBand()/2))) + ",0)";
    });





//scroll DOM element
 var mini_x_append = main.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (margin.top + height + 60) + ")")
  .attr("width", min_width);


main.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);


  //create group with all bars
  main.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .selectAll(".rect")
    .data(barsData)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.key);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("fill",barColor);




//To display bar value on bars
  main.selectAll("text.bar")
      .data(barsData)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key) + x.rangeBand()/2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) - 5; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.value+"%"; });




var xBrush = d3.svg.brush().x(min_x).on("brush", xBrushed);

//d3.svg.brush().x(groupx).on("brush", xBrushed);


var x_arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(min_height / 2)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(function(d, i) {
    return i ? -Math.PI : Math.PI;
  });

var brush_x_grab = mini_x_append.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x brush")
  .call(xBrush);

brush_x_grab.selectAll(".resize").append("path")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + min_height / 2 + ")")
  .attr("d", x_arc)
  .attr("fill","#FF0000");

brush_x_grab.selectAll("rect").attr("height", min_height).style("visibility","visible").attr("fill","#D3D3D3");




// Called to re-draw the bars on the main chart when the brush on the x axis
// has been altered.
function xBrushed() {
 
  var originalRange = main_xZoom.range();
  
  main_xZoom.domain(xBrush.empty() ? originalRange : xBrush.extent());
  
  x.rangeRoundBands([main_xZoom(originalRange[0]), main_xZoom(originalRange[1])], .2);

  groupx.rangeRoundBands([main_xZoom(originalRange[0]), main_xZoom(originalRange[1])], .2);

   main.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(barsData)
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return x.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.key);
    }); 

   main.selectAll(".bar")
   .data(barsData)
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key) + x.rangeBand()/2; })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) - 5; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.value+"%"; });

  main.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis).selectAll(".tick .groupline")
  .attr("transform", function(d,index) {
         
     return "translate(" + (x.rangeBand()/2) + ",0)";
    
    });

  main.select("g.x1.axis").call(groupAxis).selectAll(".tick")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
     var  centerPos;
      osLevelData.forEach(function(ddd){
        if(ddd.key === d){
          centerPos = ddd.centerBarPosVal;
        }
      })
     return "translate(" + (x(centerPos)+(x.rangeBand()/2)) + ",0)";
    })
  .selectAll(".tick .groupline")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
     var  centerPos;
     var  lastPos;
      osLevelData.forEach(function(ddd){
        if(ddd.key === d){
          lastPos = ddd.lastBarPosVal;
          centerPos = ddd.centerBarPosVal;
        }
      })
     return "translate(" + ((x(lastPos)+x.rangeBand()) - (x(centerPos)+(x.rangeBand()/2))) + ",0)";
    })
   
  //main.selectAll(
};

// This comes from the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321
// for wrapping long axis tick labels
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
};



// Set the initial brush selections.
// svg.select(".x.brush").call(xBrush.extent(main_xZoom.domain()));
svg.select(".x.brush").call(xBrush.extent([0, 220]));
//svg.select(".y.brush").call(yBrush.extent(mini_y0.domain()));

// Forces a refresh of the brushes and main chart based
// on the selected extents.
xBrushed();
//yBrushed();


function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

g.axis path,
g.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
g.brush rect.extent {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
   fill:#FF0000;
   
}
.resize path {
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
}
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>

  </body>
```